# While loop for function call for enabling I2C interrupts seems to be behaving weirdly

Tags: stm32, c, embedded

Trying to understand why the `while` loop is behaving weirdly.

`HAL_MasterReceiveInterrupt()` enables the control bits for I2C and continues to loop unless the STATE is READY - in other words, when the data is fully read but I see the it executing outside the while loop.
So while loop shouldn't end until the the return value from the function is `I2C_READY`

The output looks as follows:

```
RXing...
Printing buffer values...
Stopping transmission
```

Instead of:

```
RXing...
Stopping transmission
Printing buffer values // now that we are outside the loop
```

what's up with the sequence of execution?

```
I2C_State HAL_MasterReceiveInterrupt(void)
{
    I2C_State i2cState = I2C_handle_p->I2C_State;

    if (i2cState != I2C_RX_BUSY && i2cState != I2C_TX_BUSY)
    {
        printf ("RXing...\n");
        I2C_handle_p->I2C_State = I2C_RX_BUSY;

        GenerateStartCondition(I2C_handle_p);

        I2C_SetCtrlBits();   // enable i2c control bits
    }
    return i2cState;
}

static void I2C_StopTransmission(void)
{
    printf ("Stopping transmission...\n\n");

    // disable control bits
    I2C_handle_p->pI2Cx->CR2 &= ~(1 << I2C_CR2_ITEVTEN_Pos);
    I2C_handle_p->pI2Cx->CR2 &= ~(1 << I2C_CR2_ITBUFEN_Pos);

    // restore struct
    I2C_handle_p->I2C_State = I2C_READY;
    I2C_handle_p->rxBufferLength = BYTES_PER_TRANSACTION;
} 

// app.c
void ReadVal() {
  while (HAL_MasterReceiveInterrupt() != I2C_READY);
  printf ("Printing buffer values..."); // assuming I2C read operation is completed
  while(1);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Who calls the I2C_StopTransmission? But anyway, the I2C_StopTransmission sets the I2C_READY, so it shall be the last call before you execute "Printing buffer values". And HAL_MasterReceiveInterrupt changes the staus from  I2C_READY to I2C_BUSY. So the sequence is as follows:

```
"Printing buffer values"
"Printing buffer values"
"Printing buffer values"
n x times

"RXing..."
"Stopping transmission..."
"Printing buffer values"
"Printing buffer values"
"Printing buffer values"
n x times
```

EDIT:

```
 if (i2cState != I2C_RX_BUSY && i2cState != I2C_TX_BUSY)
```

if it's not rx_busy and it's not tx_ busy then

```
I2C_handle_p->I2C_State = I2C_RX_BUSY;
```

?? then it's rx_busy??

Further, you ask a state that obviously is set by system and then you override it?

Comment: ah, so the initial value stored in i2cState is `I2C_READY`, hence the while loop doesn't get executed to begin with. But there's still a strange behavior that I'm not able to understand regarding getting out of the while loop even though `i2cState` is not `I2C_READY` (hence the prints). also, would it be better to add say `I2C_NOTREADY` so the initial value is not `I2C_READY`?

in regards to later comment, the initial value is not expected to be either `I2C_RX_BUSY` or `I2C_TX_BUSY`